# Elastic Search - Any way to set filter in CountRequestBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to set filters in a CountRequestBuilder like we have setFilter() in  SearchRequestBuilder. Because of this I am unable to use CountRequestBuilder and using as below

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchBuilder = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(typeName).setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setExplain(true);           
SearchResponse response = searchBuilder.execute().actionGet();
Long count = response.getHits().getTotalHits();
```

Any other ways to get count of search filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top level filter is special construct that should be used only in a few particular cases such as filtering results without filtering corresponding facets. So, the best way to solve this issue is by replacing top level filter with `QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(...)`. Alternatively, you can use `SearchType.COUNT` instead of `SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH` to get back just counts.